# Calculation data 3 different columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want ask calculation process using SQL Server, right now the calculation based on Excel. But I want convert to SQL Server for example Total Avg the row number 4 is 13% is sum column total Avg from row number 3 is 0% + column C(%) from row number 4 is 50% and divide by Field Day  at row number is 4

```
(0%+50%) / 4   then I get 13%
```

Then for row number 5 for column Total Avg how I get 3% is row no 4 at column Total Avg 13% + column C% at row number 5 is 0% and divide by column Day row number 5 is 0% it should be

**(13%+0%)/5** and value Total Avg at row number 5 should be **3%**

[image: 1]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hi Nazrin. Could you please edit your question to add what you tried so far and what are the issues you are facing with your solution, so we can try and help you solve those problems?

Comment: `(LAG([total Avg]) OVER (ORDER BY [Day]) + [C(%)]) / [Day]`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a recursive CTE. To match the calculation in Excel, it is `round()` and then `convert()` to `int`. You may remove these and leave the result in decimal.

```
with rcte as
(
    select A, B, C, D, T = convert(int, round(C * 1.0 / D, 0))
    from   tbl
    where  D = 1
    
    union all
    
    select t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D, T = convert(int, round((r.T + t.C) * 1.0 / t.D, 0))
    from   rcte r
           inner join tbl t on r.D + 1 = t.D
)
select *
from   rcte
```